# Sorting more than one column

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sort

I have a file which has content that looks like this:

```
19.58 1925 Alpha
20.40 1924 Otter
13.66 1920 Gold
```

I am trying to sort it "column by column" to output the following:

```
13.40 1920 Alpha
19.58 1924 Gold
20.66 1925 Otter
```

I have tried various combinations of code, e.g.:

```
cat files | sort -t. -k1,1n | sort -t " " -k2,2n -k3,3r k4,4n
```

but this doesn't output the wanted result. How could I achieve the sorting that I mentioned?

Comment: See also: [sort and uniq columns individually](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/213701)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf "%s.%s %s %s\n" $(paste <(awk -F'[. ]' '{print $1}' file | sort -n) <(awk -F'[. ]' '{print $2}' file | sort -n) <(awk -F'[. ]' '{print $3}' file | sort -n) <(awk -F'[. ]' '{print $4}' file | sort))
```

Output:

```
13.40 1920 Alpha
19.58 1924 Gold
20.66 1925 Otter
```

Comment: thanks . but how could i achieve "13.40" not "13.66" and so on result?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU `awk`, then sorting can be done with a little help from special array `PROCINFO`:

```
awk -F '[. ]' '{for(i=1;i<NF+1;i++) a[i][NR]=$i} \
    END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"; \
        for(j=1;j<NF+1;j++){ I=0; for(i in a[j]) A[++I][j]=a[j][i]} \
            for(i=1;i<NR+1;i++){ printf A[i][1]"."; \
                for(j=2;j<NF+1;j++) printf A[i][j]" "; printf "\n"}}' file
```

The above may look complicated at first, but in fact is very simply - it just store the whole file in the array `a`, and at the end resort it to array `A` as desired. The main trick is to use `@val_num_asc` as we want to sort the columns by values in numeral ascending order.

It is should work for any number of rows and columns, just keep in mind that the whole file is stored in the memory so can be slow for large tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in 1 2 3 4
do
    tr . " " < "${1:?}" | cut -d' ' -f$i | sort > $$-$i
done

paste -d. $$-[12] | paste -d' ' - $$-[34]

rm $$-[1234]
```